# how to remove ie render id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have radio button in my pages, what i want to do is pretty easy, once radio1 is checked, then unchecked radio2, else radio1 is unchecked

```
<asp:RadioButton  id="rdlMember" runat="server" Text="Member"
 onClick ="mtdMode(this.id);" />


<asp:RadioButton id="rdlNonMember" runat="server" Text="Non Member" 
 onClick ="mtdMode(this.id);" />
```

i have created a javascript function in my pages

```
 function mtdMode(ClientID) {

    var id = ClientID.split("_").pop();
    var rdlMember= document.getElementById("rdlMember");
    var rdlNonMember= document.getElementById("rdlNonMember");

    if (id == "rdlMember") {       

    rdlNonMember.checked = false;


    } else if (id == "rdlNonMember") {

    rdlMember.checked = false;

    } 

};
```

this is not working, however i checked my id from ie developer tool, this id format is render as below and if i change my code as below then work, however this is not my objective, is that any others way to get radiobutton id?

```
document.getElementById
("ctl00_m_g_2d869ad7_689c_4d9b_88b8_774ae48d99ab_ctl00_rdlNonMember").checked = false;



document.getElementById
("ctl00_m_g_2d869ad7_689c_4d9b_88b8_774ae48d99ab_ctl00_rdlMember").checked = false;
```

Comment: How are you calling this method? That looks like something else not IE that is changing the ID. Perhaps some third party library?

Comment: perhaps is sharepoint?i am not sure, my level is not good enough to debug it yet =(

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons do that by default when they have the same name. You need to use `GroupName` in the `<asp:RadioButton />` tags.

See http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_radiobutton.asp

The plain HTML example is at http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: my radiobutton is inside <td> when i inserted <form> in my <td> it broke my Ui design, beside doing checked and unchecked i am doing others function as well, however thank for your lesson =)

Comment: I don't see how tables and `tr`s relate to this. I think you are trying to emulate a behavior that is given to you by default. Why bypass it?